# Basic Auth in Clojure with clj-http

Tags: clojure, basic-authentication

We're using [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http) to do HTTP basic authentication.  I want to send a request with this header:

```
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

All the examples I've found say to do it [like this](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#usage):

```
(clj-http.client/get "http://my.domain.com" 
                     {:headers {:basic-auth [username password]}})
```

This seems to send a request that just contains a header called `basic-auth`, with unencoded values for `username` and `password`.  I'm having to manually generate the basic auth header like this:

```
(clj-http.client/get "http://my.domain.com"
                     {:headers {:Authorization "Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ="}})
```

Of course, that's much harder because I have to encode the username and password properly and stick the word "Basic" on the front.  Can clj-http do this for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `:basic-auth` key goes into the top level of the request map, not under `:headers`:

```
(clj-http.client/get "http://my.domain.com" 
                     {:basic-auth [username password]})
```