# Clojure GET request of ShipStation using clj-http.client

Tags: clojure, clj-http

I'm trying to use a GET request using clj-http.client from ShipStation and getting a 401 error,

they have lots of examples of different languages of how to do this. Javascript seems easy:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Host", "ssapi.shipstation.com");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "username:password");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://ssapi.shipstation.com/orders/orderId", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Here is my clojure client/get code which works fine without headers and using {:async? true} from other websites such as jsonplaceholder:

```
(client/get "https://ssapi.shipstation.com/shipments?shipDateStart=2023-01-05&shipDateEnd=2023-01-05"
            {:header { "Host" "ssapi.shipstation.com" "Authorization" "username:password"}}
            (fn [response] (println "hello" (get response :body)))
            (fn [exception] (println "exception message is: " (.getMessage exception))))
```

can someone help me with the format of this GET request?

Comment: I thought it was `:headers`? https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#get

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to calling shipstation api in clj-http:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25794180/21046503

```
(clj-http.client/get "http://my.domain.com" 
                 {:basic-auth [username password]})
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#basic-auth) it looks like you want:

```
(client/get "https://ssapi.shipstation.com/shipments"
        {:async? true
         :basic-auth "username:password"
         :query-params {:shipDateStart "2023-01-05" :shipDateEnd "2023-01-05"
         :as :json}
        (fn [response] (println "hello" (get response :body)))
        (fn [exception] (println "exception message is: " (.getMessage exception))))
```

That presumes that Basic-Auth is in play which is what the endpoint and api docs suggest but I'm not a shistation user